# Linux sys_call_table rip relative addressing x86_64

Tags: linux, system-calls

I am trying to get offset of sys_call_table on Linux x86_64.

First of all I read pointer to system_call entry by reading it from MSR_LSTAR and it's correct

```c
static unsigned long read_msr(unsigned int msr)
{

    unsigned low, high;
    asm volatile("rdmsr" : "=a" (low), "=d" (high) : "c" (msr));
    return ((low) | ((u64)(high) << 32));
}
```

Then I parse it to find opcode of call instruction and it is also correct

```c
#define CALL_OP 0xFF
#define CALL_MODRM 0x14
static unsigned long find_syscall_table(unsigned char *ptr)
{

  //correct
  for (; (*ptr != CALL_OP) || (*(ptr+1) != CALL_MODRM); ptr++);

  //not correct
  ptr += *(unsigned int*)(ptr + 3);
  pr_info("%lx", (unsigned long)ptr);


  return ptr;
}
```

But I failed to get address after call opcode. First byte of ptr is opcode, then ModRM byte, then SIB and then 32bit displacement, so I add 3 to ptr and dereferenced it as integer value and then add it to ptr, because it is %RIP, and address is RIP relative. But the result value is wrong, it don't coincide with value I see in gdb, so where am I wrong?

Comment: What goal are you actually trying to accomplish by means of this digging around in internals?

Comment: The goal is to patch sys_call_table in runtime. I want to do this exatly in way described above, but I cant find out why doesnt it work

Comment: As i wrote before, system_call entry and offset of "call *sys_call_table(,%rax,8)" is right, i checked it in gdb allready. I think I am failing with RIP relative adresing, but dont know exactly where

Comment: That's why I'm saying dump out the binary data from the starting point of the search, preferably with a disassembly next to it, so you can run the algorithm by hand and see what doesn't make sense.  Somewhere there is an unwarranted assumption.

Comment: ffffffff8145fe62:       ff 14 c5 00 13 60 81    callq  *-0x7e9fed00(,%rax,8)                 i dont understand how "00 13 60 81" become 0x7e9fed00, and even in this case ffffffff8145fe62+7e9fed00 != sys_call_table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not x7e9fed00 but rather -0x7e9fed00 - a negative displacement.

That is the sign-magnitude form of the 2's complement negative number 0x81601300

which is stored by a little-endian processor as "00 13 60 81"

---

No idea if you will find sys_call_table at the resulting address however.  As an alternative idea, it seems some people find it by searching memory for the known pointers to functions that should be listed in it.

Comment: ffffffff8145fe62-7e9fed00=0xFFFFFFFF02A61162  this result i get in my module and calculator. Objdump and gdb show offset of table ffffffff81601300 (

Comment: ffffffff8145fe62 it is offset of call instruction

Comment: If ffffffff81601300  is the correct answer, given that "81601300" is the literal you found stored little-endian in memory, it appears that this isn't a signed offset relative to the current IP, but rather an unsigned offset within the current "segment" (or whatever one should call the high word 32 bits of the current address).  GDB may be just throwing you a curveball by assuming it is signed and displaying it as a negative number.  Probably worth double-checking on the exact meaning of that instruction.